# How do I spoon feed an IObservable from procedural code?

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

Most sample codes around Reactive Extensions revolves around how you compose logic and operators on the sequence.

The parts around Observable generation focus around "FromEventPatter","FromAsynch" etc.

```
IObservable<string> observableHotStatus = ??;
foreach (var task in todo)
{
   //Process task;
   //Post status message into observable; How do I do this?
}
```

In short, I want an object that I can post into, like an ActionBlock, Action (of T) or something like that.
What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Examining your code more closely, I'd recommend using `Observable.Create`. Even though it only returns a *cold* observable, you can apply the `Publish` operator to the generated observable to make it *hot*.

And if by `task` you're actually referring to `Task<T>`, then you can use an overload of `Observable.Create` that allows you to define an async iterator. For example:

```
IObservable<string> statuses = Observable.Create<string>(
  (observer, cancel) =>
  {
    foreach (var task in todo)
    {
      cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

      await task;
      observer.OnNext("Status");
    }
  });
```

**Previous Answer:**

You could use one of the following types, but I suggest reading [To Use Subject or Not To Use Subject](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) first before making your decision.

- `Subject<T>`: General purpose, "event"-like, [hot observable](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx). Calling `OnNext` is like raising a classic .NET event.
- `BehaviorSubject<T>`: Generally used as the backing field for a property, it represents an observable sequence of change "events". Whenever an observer subscribes, it receives the current value immediately, followed by all changes to the property. You can extract the current value at any time from the `Value` property; e.g., within your property's getter. Call `OnNext` within your property's setter and you don't have to keep a duplicate backing field. It's also Rx's version of a [continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) and it's the only [FRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming)-like thing you'll find in Rx, if my understanding of FRP is correct.
- `ReplaySubject<T>`: Generally used as an historical buffer of "events", it represents an observable sequence of values beginning with the values that have been missed by an observer, whenever an observer subscribes. You can control how far back values are buffered; it's like a sliding window over the history of values. You rarely have to use this type. In most cases, the `Observable.Replay` operator will do.
- `AsyncSubject<T>`: Generally used to capture the results of *hot*, asynchronous functions like `Task<T>`. You rarely have to use this type. In most cases, `Observable.FromAsyncPattern` or `Task`-conversion operators will do.

Comment: Subject<T> did it for me. I will take the concerns into consideration. Thank you.

Comment: +2 of possible! This answer have probably thought me more than anything else in a while. Tanks!